# Using Ctypes to call complicated c++ code

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

My question is based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145649/8408902). What's different is that in my C++ code, I have a function that initiates an object of a self-defined class *within that function*. In my python code, I simply want to call that function. I don't need to create an object of the self-defined class in Python. For example, there are three files in my C++ code

**foo.h**

```
class foo {

public: 
        foo();
        void bar();
        int a;


};
```

**foo.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
    foo::foo () {
      a = 5;
    }


    void foo::bar(){
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    };
}
```

**mainFunc.cpp**

```
extern "C" {
    void printStuff (int addNum) {
        foo fooArg;
        fooArg.a = fooArg.a + addNum;
        std::cout<<"Printing..."<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<fooArg.a<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

In my Python code, I want to create a Python function that calls `printStuff` in `mainFunc.cpp`. I don't need to initiate an object of `foo` in Python. However, two questions:

(1) Did I use `extern "C"` correctly?

(2) How should I compile these three files into a shared library? I use g++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (1) Did I use extern "C" correctly?

Don't put `extern ”C"` around the method definitions.

The purpose of `extern "C"` is to tell the compiler that some function needs to be accessible as a C function—that is, called by C code, or by `ctypes` or some other library that loads and calls functions out of shared objects.

The only function you want to call through `ctypes` is `printStuff`, so only that function should be `extern "C"`.

Trying to `extern "C"` the methods will probably harmlessly do nothing with `g++` (they'll still end up named something like `__ZN3foo3barEv` in the export table), but you may get a warning, or even a non-running library, with a different compiler.

---

> (2) How should I compile these three files into a shared library? I use g++.

You probably want to write a `Makefile` or use some other build system, but if you want to do it manually:

```
g++ -shared -o foo.so foo.cpp mainFunc.cpp
```

Depending on your platform, you may also need to manually specify [`-fPIC` or `-fpic`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#Code-Gen-Options).<sup>1</sup>

If you want to do the steps separately:

```
g++ -c foo.cpp
g++ -c mainFunc.cpp
g++ -shared -o foo.so foo.o mainFunc.o
```

In this case, if a PIC flag is needed, it goes on the first two lines.

---

And now, to use it from Python:

```
$ python3
>>> import ctypes
>>> foo = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('foo.so')
>>> foo.printStuff(10)
Printing...
15
>>> foo.printStuff("abc")
Printing...
116480373
```

Of course it's generally better to set the `argtypes` and `restype` instead of making `ctypes` guess. It guessed that the Python `int` 10 should be converted to the C `int` 10, which worked great, but it also guessed that the Python `str` "abc" should be converted to a C `const char *`, and you end up with the low 32 bits of the pointer to the string buffer being used as an `int`. So:

```
>>> foo.printStuff.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
>>> foo.printStuff.restype = None
>>> foo.printStuff(10)
Printing...
15
>>> foo.printStuff("abc")
ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

And you may want to write a `foo.py` that wraps that up:

```
import ctypes
foo = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('foo.so')
foo.printStuff.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int]
foo.printStuff.restype = None
printStuff = foo.printStuff
```

---

<sub>1. From quick tests, I didn't need it for x86_64 macOS, x86 macOS, or x86_64 Linux, but PowerPC Linux needs `-fpic` and ARM64 Linux needs `-fPIC`. However, I didn't actually run all of those. And, other than macOS (where I made sure to test with Homebrew gcc 8.2 and Apple Clang 9.1) I don't know which compiler version I had.</sub>

Comment: Great answer. On my machine, I had to compile with `-fPIC`. Do you have to do that?